# Qt QString maxsplit argument

Tags: qt, qstring

Python strings have a function `split()` that can take a `maxsplit` argument (from [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)):

> If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done (thus, the list
>   will have at most maxsplit+1 elements). If maxsplit is not specified
>   or -1, then there is no limit on the number of splits (all possible
>   splits are made).

Can QStrings do this? I looked at the docs and there's no `split()` overload that takes an integer equivalent to `maxsplit` as argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't seem like it, though it seems to be trivial to implement -

```
QString str("How are all of you doing");
QStringList list = str.split(' ').mid(0, maxSplit);
QString remainingStr = str.section(' ', maxSplit);
list << remainingStr;
```

Or if you want to be more performant, you can just copy the code from QString::split, and add the extra feature. The code is there at [qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qstring.cpp](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/blobs/stable/src/corelib/tools/qstring.cpp#line6405). You just need to add `&& list.size() <= maxSplit` in the while loop.